# How do I stop Comodo Internet Security's antivirus from automatically downloading updates?

Tags: download, anti-virus, updates

Quite simply there is no option that says *Disable automatic updates*. I know there are two options that allow you to specify if you want Comodo to update before scans, but I don't think those will stop random updates.

Also is there anyway to stop an update in progress. The only button on the update window is Hide.

I'm low on Internet download quota and desperately need a better option than 'Stop all activities' to block network use from everything.

Note: I'm referring to virus signature updates, not program updates.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Fake Name: Quite simply because it hogs bandwidth, and I'd rather update it when I am at uni or work where download quota isn't important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, open the COMODO, 
then open ANTIVIRUS

go to SCANNER SETTINGS

On the REAL TIME SCANNING tab,

disable AUTOMATICALLY UPDATE VIRUS DATABASE BEFORE SCANNING.

also in MANUAL SCANNING too.

in SCHEDULED SCANNING Tab, you've to disable the automatically update and show scanning process.

Hope this helps

also , you could drop it from start-up programs by run > msconfig > Startup

Comment: You know what, you're right. That did stop the random updating, now instead it gives me a balloon notification.